# name not defined? -laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Greetings to all readers!

I ran into an interesting error, I want to create a button + input field, but whatever I try, I keep getting the error `route [name] not defined`.

## index.blade.php:

```html
<form action="{{ route('user.panel.fachecker') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="facode" class="input-user" placeholder="Code here..." />
    <button type="submit"><span>Check</span></button>
</form>
```

## web.php:

```php
Route::post('/', 'PanelController@fachecker')->name('user.panel.fachecker');
```

## PanelController.php:

```php
public function fachecker(FARequest $request)
{
    $facode = $request->input('facode');

    if ($facode)
    { 
        Flash::success($facode);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    Flash::error(trans('welcome.txt-215'));
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Log:**
[image]

This button does not redirect, only the function should run and display with flash

Thank you very much in advance for your answers and help! Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: have you tried `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: You will probably also need to add @CSRF to your form, otherwise you will get a 419 Error

Comment: It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: could you add all of the `web.php` file? or at least could you check that you don't have any other route with the same url?

Comment: You could also try to call `php artisan view:cache` and `php artisan view:clear`directly. 
I would also like to see your routes, are you sure that using `/` is not already used as a home route?

Comment: I was wrong first, I checked and it exists '/'

Comment: If the route is in a group and the group itself has a name then that name is prefixed in all members of the group so check if your route is in a group with a name

Answer (score -1):

If the value was incorrect at one point and the routes are cached. If you dont have access to the terminal due to shared hosting.

Could you not go into /bootstrap/cache/routes and delete that file. This should then no longer have the file cached.